# Miniproject - single instruction

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i want to make this instruccion for the turtlebot:

> $ turtle_walk with_SPEED with_DIRECTION

turtle_walk allows to move the motors of the turtlebot with certain speed and in certain direction, but i don want to do something like keyboard_teleop that stays in a cicle and waits for the user.

For example:

> $ shh turtle@turtlebot

> $ turtle_walk foo bar

And the result is that the robot was able to move it self ONE STEP no more and the terminal can receive another diferent instruction.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202236/miniproject---single-instruction/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

try it this way from bash

https://github.com/mockbot/MockBot/blob/master/mockbot/bin/cmd_vel_test.sh

You can replace static cmd_vel values by variables ($1,$2...) and customize your script .

Enjoy it :-)
Christian

---

Originally posted by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) with karma: 390 on 2015-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-02**:
Hi, this solution induces the turtlebot in a loop and the robot still without moving

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-02**:
It shows the basic principle. You'd need this to run in your code for as long as you define a step to be.